# Sub site in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nopcommerce

My site is yourdomain.com & I want to add staging/demo site as youdomain.com/demo so I added virtual directory into my default web site & converted it into application.

But when I try to access the site youdomain.com/demo then it doesn't show site properly & gives file not found error for all js/css file. I think youdomain.com/demo site pointing to root site? but My path of subsite is correct & Binding is to 127.0.0.1. Can you tell us what we missing ? Our site is into MVC5 on IIS7.

Comment: So only your .js and .css files are not found?

Comment: how did you refer you js and css in your layout ? is it relative ?

Comment: Yes only for JS, images & CSS file. Code for both youdomain.com & youdomain.com/demo is same. youdomain.com works fine in my case but not demo. Path is relative.

Comment: Any update on above ?